# Send variable from Javascript to textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have searched Google for the past hour and can't find the answer to this. I have a variable and I need to send it to a text box to be the default value:

```
if (totalcustomamount < 105)  {
          totalcustomamount = 105;
}
```

is my code and it works, but I don't know how to set the variable there to that value in the textbox below:

```
<input name="name_of_box" type="text" id="name_of_box" size="4" class="name_of_class">
```

I normally would just put `value="something"`, but I need to use the variable that is in the JavaScript. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// id="name_of_box"
document.getElementById('name_of_box').value = totalcustomamount;
```

Answer (score 1):

jQuery way :

```
$(function() {
    if (totalcustomamount < 105)  {
        $("#name_of_box").val(105);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (totalcustomamount < 105)  {
          totalcustomamount = 105;
        document.getElementById('name_of_box').value = totalcustomamount;

}
```